# how to draw route between two location in apple map. by openURL

Tags: ios, swift, location, apple-maps

in my app, i am getting source and destination address of the location. now by using that lat-long I want to draw route between that two location and I want to open it in apple maps.
right now I am using this

```
 let url = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=\(destlat),\(destlong)&dirflg=d")!

        print(url)
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
```

but this is only showing me two location and showing that "**Route is not available**"

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let urlString = "http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=\(latStart),\(lngStart)&daddr=\(latEnd),\(lngEnd)&dirflg=d"
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

1. pass **latStart**,**lngStart** as a your **currentlocation**
2. pass **latEnd**,**lngEnd** as a your 
   **destinationlocation**.
3. More info show this link. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html